# iOS: is calling methods of UIApplication in thread other than the main thread safe?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiapplication

Some say that one must use UIApplication in main thread, but I don't see this documented in Apple's doc.
So can someone please tell me if it is safe to use UIApplication in a separate thread? If it is not safe, where is this documented?

**EDIT:**
I'm focusing on those methods which manipulate local notifications.

Comment: It would help if you were more specific about the methods you wanted to use.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you, I've added those methods I'm inspecting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most UIKit classes are not thread safe. This has been discussed at length at WWDC, etc, but it is not very well documented. The best I could find is [TN2109](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2109/_index.html) which repeatedly discusses how calling UIKit from a secondary thread is not permitted.

Note that there are many documented exceptions to this rule. For example, the [beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623031-beginbackgroundtask) and related methods on UIApplication are clearly labeled as safe to call from non-main threads. (This also implies that the other methods of UIApplication are *not* safe to call from other threads, since these are specifically called out.)

There are other exceptions to this rule as well, mostly involving drawing (UIImage, and UIColor instances are thread-safe, as of [iOS 4](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009559-SW29), at least).

Answer (score 0):

UIApplication is a subclass of UIResponder and is part of the UIKit framework. So I guess it is not thread safe because it is documented that UIKit classes are not thread safe.

Also it has methods like – setStatusBarOrientation:animated:, which are all UI based and those definitely cannot be called in another thread than the main thread.

Comment: When you manipulate the UI it must be on the main thread, but not all UIApplication methods manipulate the UI. In those cases using on other threads is fine.

Comment: I've edited my question, I'm focusing on methods that manipulates local notifications.